# Getting error when pushing code to git branch

Tags: git, push, pull, upstream-branch

I'm trying to push code to my branch and I haven't made any commits to the branch previously. git add and git commit work fine but when I do git push, I get the following error:

fatal: The current branch my_branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin my_branch
```

When I run the suggested command, I get another error:

fatal: my_branch cannot be resolved to branch

I tried git pull too and that works fine but when I do git pull specifically for my branch like, I get another error:

```
git pull origin my_branch
```

fatal: couldn't find remote ref my_branch

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: `git push --set-upstream` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped but I was able to fix the issue by doing this:

1. created a new branch
2. git branch -u origin/master (this is to set a remote branch for my branch)
3. committed changes on the new branch

//git indicated that my branch and master branch have diverged so I did step 4

4. git pull
5. Resolved conflicts
6. git push origin HEAD (used HEAD to push to the remote version of my branch)

I found this link helpful:
https://intellipaat.com/community/21465/git-status-on-branch-master-nothing-to-commit-working-tree-clean-however-with-changes-commited

Also, creating a new branch may not be necessary, as long as other steps are the same.